# How can I force jQuery Mobile to run my js code every time it loads a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have noticed that at some point some of my pages are not behaving like I would expect. It seems not to run my js code, which is something like this:

```
 // DB
 db_manager = new DB_MANAGER();
 db_manager.open(function(){
    if(db_manager.db){
       db_manager.activitati.getAllByStatus(0, function(list){
        uiHelper.showActivitati(list, $('#listView'));
        $('#listView').listview("refresh");
       })   
    }           
 });
```

How can I force it to run?

Comment: I forgot to mention: if I do a page refresh the js code works.

Comment: Can you post *all* of your code?

Comment: it works in firefox 13+; it does not work in chrome

Comment: run the code when the `pageshow` event is triggered.

Comment: I tried that, but is not enough